# MariaDB C++ Connector compile

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, mariadb, mysql-connector

I'm trying to compile a simple c++ file that is suppose to use the mariadbc++ connector. For some reason I ran into alot of trouble with that. I get strange error messages. I neither understand them, nor do I know how to fix them.
   I did a lot of research, but either nobody else ran into these problems or I just cant find them.

I installed following packages:

```
mariadb-client
mariadb-client-5.5
mariadb-server
libmariadbclient18
libmysqlclient18
libmysqlcppconn7
libmysqlcppconn-dev
libmariadbclient-dev
libmariadb-dev
```

I'm on a x64 Ubuntu 14.04 System (well Pinguy OS, but I guess, that doesn't matter)

I tried to build following programm:

```
#include <my_global.h>
#include <mysql.h>
#include "mysql_driver.h" 

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{  
  sql::mysql::MySQL_Driver *driver;
  sql::Connection *con;
  sql::Statement *stmt;
  driver = sql::mysql::MySQL_Driver::get_mysql_driver_instance();
  con = driver->connect("tcp://localhost:3306","root", "herein");
  if (!con->isValid()) exit(1);

  stmt = con->createStatement();
  stmt->execute("use testtb");

  stmt->execute("INSERT INTO Testtable(id, label) VALUES (1, 1)");
  delete stmt;
  delete con;
  return 1;
}
```

And I tried this command:

```
g++ -lmysqlcppconn -g src/test_mariadb.cpp -o bin/test_mariadb $(mysql_config --cflags) $(mysql_config --libs)
```

where under in src/ my source files are and in bin/ my binaries.

And finally the Compile Errors I get:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/char_traits.h:39:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/ios:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/iostream:39,
                 from /usr/include/boost/assert.hpp:82,
                 from /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/scoped_ptr.hpp:15,
                 from /usr/include/boost/scoped_ptr.hpp:14,
                 from /usr/include/mysql_driver.h:30,
                 from src/test_mariadb.cpp:3:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algobase.h:239:56: error: macro "min" passed 3 arguments, but takes just 2
     min(const _Tp& __a, const _Tp& __b, _Compare __comp)
                                                        ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algobase.h:260:56: error: macro "max" passed 3 arguments, but takes just 2
     max(const _Tp& __a, const _Tp& __b, _Compare __comp)
                                                        ^
In file included from /usr/include/boost/mpl/aux_/begin_end_impl.hpp:21:0,
                 from /usr/include/boost/mpl/begin_end.hpp:18,
                 from /usr/include/boost/mpl/iter_fold.hpp:18,
                 from /usr/include/boost/variant/detail/initializer.hpp:28,
                 from /usr/include/boost/variant/variant.hpp:31,
                 from /usr/include/boost/variant.hpp:17,
                 from /usr/include/cppconn/connection.h:31,
                 from /usr/include/cppconn/driver.h:30,
                 from /usr/include/mysql_driver.h:32,
                 from src/test_mariadb.cpp:3:
/usr/include/boost/mpl/aux_/has_begin.hpp:20:57: error: macro "test" passed 2 arguments, but takes just 1
 BOOST_MPL_HAS_XXX_TRAIT_NAMED_DEF(has_begin, begin, true)
                                                         ^
In file included from /usr/include/boost/mpl/sequence_tag.hpp:18:0,
                 from /usr/include/boost/mpl/begin_end.hpp:19,
                 from /usr/include/boost/mpl/iter_fold.hpp:18,
                 from /usr/include/boost/variant/detail/initializer.hpp:28,
                 from /usr/include/boost/variant/variant.hpp:31,
                 from /usr/include/boost/variant.hpp:17,
                 from /usr/include/cppconn/connection.h:31,
                 from /usr/include/cppconn/driver.h:30,
                 from /usr/include/mysql_driver.h:32,
                 from src/test_mariadb.cpp:3:
/usr/include/boost/mpl/aux_/has_tag.hpp:20:54: error: macro "test" passed 2 arguments, but takes just 1
 BOOST_MPL_HAS_XXX_TRAIT_NAMED_DEF(has_tag, tag, false)
                                                      ^
In file included from /usr/include/boost/mpl/aux_/O1_size_impl.hpp:20:0,
                 from /usr/include/boost/mpl/O1_size.hpp:19,
                 from /usr/include/boost/mpl/iter_fold.hpp:19,
                 from /usr/include/boost/variant/detail/initializer.hpp:28,
                 from /usr/include/boost/variant/variant.hpp:31,
                 from /usr/include/boost/variant.hpp:17,
                 from /usr/include/cppconn/connection.h:31,
                 from /usr/include/cppconn/driver.h:30,
                 from /usr/include/mysql_driver.h:32,
                 from src/test_mariadb.cpp:3:
/usr/include/boost/mpl/aux_/has_size.hpp:20:1: error: macro "test" passed 2 arguments, but takes just 1
 BOOST_MPL_HAS_XXX_TRAIT_DEF(size)
 ^
In file included from /usr/include/boost/mpl/apply_wrap.hpp:23:0,
                 from /usr/include/boost/mpl/bind.hpp:27,
                 from /usr/include/boost/mpl/lambda.hpp:18,
                 from /usr/include/boost/mpl/iter_fold.hpp:20,
                 from /usr/include/boost/variant/detail/initializer.hpp:28,
                 from /usr/include/boost/variant/variant.hpp:31,
                 from /usr/include/boost/variant.hpp:17,
                 from /usr/include/cppconn/connection.h:31,
                 from /usr/include/cppconn/driver.h:30,
                 from /usr/include/mysql_driver.h:32,
                 from src/test_mariadb.cpp:3:
/usr/include/boost/mpl/aux_/has_apply.hpp:22:58: error: macro "test" passed 2 arguments, but takes just 1
 BOOST_MPL_HAS_XXX_TRAIT_NAMED_DEF(has_apply, apply, false)
                                                          ^
In file included from /usr/include/boost/mpl/quote.hpp:23:0,
                 from /usr/include/boost/mpl/aux_/full_lambda.hpp:25,
                 from /usr/include/boost/mpl/lambda.hpp:22,
                 from /usr/include/boost/mpl/iter_fold.hpp:20,
                 from /usr/include/boost/variant/detail/initializer.hpp:28,
                 from /usr/include/boost/variant/variant.hpp:31,
                 from /usr/include/boost/variant.hpp:17,
                 from /usr/include/cppconn/connection.h:31,
                 from /usr/include/cppconn/driver.h:30,
                 from /usr/include/mysql_driver.h:32,
                 from src/test_mariadb.cpp:3:
/usr/include/boost/mpl/aux_/has_type.hpp:20:55: error: macro "test" passed 2 arguments, but takes just 1
 BOOST_MPL_HAS_XXX_TRAIT_NAMED_DEF(has_type, type, true)
                                                       ^
In file included from src/test_mariadb.cpp:1:0:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algobase.h:193:5: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘const’
     min(const _Tp& __a, const _Tp& __b)
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algobase.h:193:5: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘const’
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algobase.h:193:5: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘const’
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algobase.h:193:5: error: expected initializer before ‘const’
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algobase.h:216:5: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘const’
     max(const _Tp& __a, const _Tp& __b)
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algobase.h:216:5: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘const’
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algobase.h:216:5: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘const’
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algobase.h:216:5: error: expected initializer before ‘const’
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/char_traits.h:39:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/ios:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8/iostream:39,
                 from /usr/include/boost/assert.hpp:82,
                 from /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/scoped_ptr.hpp:15,
                 from /usr/include/boost/scoped_ptr.hpp:14,
                 from /usr/include/mysql_driver.h:30,
                 from src/test_mariadb.cpp:3:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algobase.h:239:5: error: ‘std::min’ declared as an ‘inline’ variable
     min(const _Tp& __a, const _Tp& __b, _Compare __comp)
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algobase.h:239:5: error: template declaration of ‘const _Tp& std::min’
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algobase.h:242:7: error: expected primary-expression before ‘if’
       if (__comp(__b, __a))
       ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algobase.h:242:7: error: expected ‘}’ before ‘if’
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algobase.h:244:7: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘return’
       return __a;
       ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algobase.h:260:5: error: ‘max’ declared as an ‘inline’ variable
     max(const _Tp& __a, const _Tp& __b, _Compare __comp)
     ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algobase.h:260:5: error: template declaration of ‘const _Tp& max’
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algobase.h:263:7: error: expected primary-expression before ‘if’
       if (__comp(__a, __b))
       ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algobase.h:263:7: error: expected ‘}’ before ‘if’
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algobase.h:265:7: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘return’
       return __a;
       ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algobase.h:266:5: error: expected declaration before ‘}’ token
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A header you have included has defined preprocessor macros named `min`, `max` and `test`. These have then conflicted with identifiers used (e.g. for method names) in other header files you have included.

Assuming that those macros have been defined in one of these headers:

```
#include <my_global.h>
#include <mysql.h>
```

you could add `#undef`s before you include `mysql_driver.h`, e.g.:

```
#include <my_global.h>
#include <mysql.h>
#undef min
#undef max
#undef test
#include "mysql_driver.h"
```

You could also consider re-arranging the order in which you include the files, or look into what headers are defining these and see whether the definition of these macros can be disabled.

Comment: Thanks alot, it was actually a problem with including the headers my_global.h, mysql.h. They messed up the cppconnector. I just removed them and everything copiled just fine!